# I want to fetch the version of list in SharePoint using client object model. How do I do it?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to fetch the version of list in SharePoint using client object model. How do I do it? Also please let me know what references I need to add apart from using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client. I am stuck with this issue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the list version settings using client object model with `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List.MajorVersionLimit` & `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit`.

If you stuck with CSOM API then download the latest [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Also Follow this link for more info: [Latest API updates in Client Side Object Model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2014/12/15/latest-api-updates-in-client-side-object-model-dec-2014-cu-for-sp2013/)

Comment: if you can share the code ? I tried so many things..not able to get it